Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name
I have problem with DNS resolving in my WSL1, here is the example:
[rootname@hostname ~]# yum update
CentOS Stream 8 - AppStream                                                             0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'appstream':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://vault.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml [Could not resolve host: vault.centos.org]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

Ping to vault.centos.org returns:
64 bytes from server-18-66-27-78.vie50.r.cloudfront.net (18.66.27.78): icmp_seq=4 ttl=246 time=54.6 ms

curl -G www.example.net returns content of html:
<html>
<<ANY_CONTENT>>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Where is problem of this Error, when DNS resolving de-facto works? How solve it? Thanks

Is there a static route entry for 18.66.27.78? My DNS resolves vault.centos.org as 52.222.191.103…

Hi JozefZ, static route entry is ok, and system works normally.

Have you considered updating to WSL2? I know this isn't what you asked but in general there are less problems.

Fila: are those WSL(CentOS) ping and curl, or Windows (native) ones? What does WSL nslookup say, and is it same as Windows nslookup? @JosefZ: since that domain is on a CDN (cloudfront) its DNS returns different addresses to people in different parts of the world; https://dnschecker.org/#A/vault.centos.org shows at least several (and there might be more)

Hi Dave, all works, but updating with yum not. nslookup is not yet installed in basic linux installation.

Friend, I was told that this is due to the end of support for Centos repositories of older versions
I found this way to fix it. Just run these three commands and your repositories will be updated. This is true for Centos-7 and Centos-8
sed -i s/mirror.centos.org/vault.centos.org/g /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo

sed -i s/^#.*baseurl=http/baseurl=http/g /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo

sed -i s/^mirrorlist=http/#mirrorlist=http/g /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo


This is for the quite different problem of failing to resolve mirrorlist.centos.org which did in fact vanish at EOL, NOT vault.centos.org which still exists

https://vault.centos.org/

Solved, after reading yum executable. yum is not elf executable, but script. Fire wall blocks another application, that's base.
